# Metatag for each content

Tags: 7

I ve used [MetaTag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) to change the tags in my node . but this changes me to all nodes. I want different tags for different nodes Is there any possiblities to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question. You can globally change all metatag information at /admin/config/search/metatags. To change the meta information on a per-node basis, edit the node and click on the Meta Tags tab at the bottom. You can then update the meta information for that specific node:

[image: meta tags per node]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Meta tags quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) module. On every single page you will see link to change meta info for that page.